# Redirecting to view page from action in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using ajax $.post call to redirect to action which is Index, from Index I need to call its View Page, while debugging its going to view page ,but I cant see the same in browser. Here is my ajax code and action code:

AJAX code:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function () {       
    var val=$('#whereSearch').val();         
    $.post("Search/Index/",{where:val});       
});
```

ACTION Code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string where)            
{     
    var q = searchQuery(where);  
    ViewBag.val = q;         
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using AJAX for this? You'll get your view passed back as data, you won't get a redirect. Just do this:

```
 $("#btnSearch").click(function (e) { 
     e.preventDefault();     
     var val=$('#whereSearch').val();  
     window.location = "Search/Index/" + val;
});
```